# Receiving a network related error while trying to connect a desktop application to SQLexpress in windows authentication mode

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting a network-related or instance-specific error. I am working on a desktop application through C#.Net. The error says

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)"

My connection string is:

`string connectionString = @"Data Source=ritesh-pc\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=score;"+"IntegratedSecurity=SSPI";`

Comment: This article seems helpful for you, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: Have you verified that "the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Connection string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName; Integrated Security=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct `Server`. Try this **connection string** :

```
<add name="MyDbConn1" connectionString="Server=YourPC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
```